# Non-sampling Javascript performance analysis

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling

I'm trying to understand where the time is spent in my JS code so I can improve its performance.  The "Performance" tab of Chrome's developers' tools gives me much of what I want, allowing me to narrow things down to the function that is taking most of the time, in this case JQuery's "find" function.)  However, when I go to the "Event Log" view, it doesn't seem to show **all** of the function calls and their execution time.  I think that the reason is that Chrome is sampling the state of the code, rather than tracing each function call, and so the information is not available.

Is this correct?  If so, is there an easy alternative that doesn't require me to manually instrument all my calls?

I found the "Web Tracing Framework" which sounds like it does what I want, but installing the extension and trying to analyze a trace didn't work right off the bat.  I started digging into what was going on, but there are several known issues and the code doesn't seem to be actively maintained.  If someone can tell me it works fine, I'll be more persistent.

Otherwise, what do people use for this now-a-days?

Comment: When you say all of the function calls, I assume you refer to all the methods invoked during that particular page load and not literally "all" the JS methods defined in the entire JS file. For obvious reasons, those will not be accounted for in CDT performance tab when a particular page is loaded. Btw, the self time in event log should be indicating the time spent on a particular event which in your case would be the time spent at that particular line of method execution. Not sure what more you are expecting.

Comment: Well, yeah, just the functions that are called, but without instrumenting each in advance.  I'd like a timeline very much like the "flame chart" that is shown on the performance tab, but showing every call:  clickHandler runs from 130 to 390, calling f1() from 145 to 150 and again from 200 to 210, and f(1) called jQuery.find() from 146 to 148 and 203 to 206, etc.  I'd like a timeline very much like the "flame chart" that is shown on the performance tab, but with EVERY call and return timestamped.  My understanding is that this is different than what CDT does now, right?

Comment: I've learned that I'm looking for structural profiling, vs. sampling profiling, and I've found how to do it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxXkquTPng8  My only complaint is that I have to manually instrument the code with calls to console methods.  Why can't just say "do this for all calls"?